# Java not running bash script on Ubuntu Instance

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am trying to run a bash script on my server using Java.

The script works when tested alone using `bash pm2_StopStart.bash`

Running through Java I get no errors such as file not found or permission denied. These have all been solved.

I am using `ProcessBuilder` and followed countless examples including this [link](https://www.javasavvy.com/execute-shell-script-java-using-process-builder/)

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/ec2-user/test/pm2_StopStart.bash");
        Process p = pb.start();
        //p.waitFor();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("tmp2.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Okay. After pb.start() - " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("tmp.txt", "UTF-8");
            writer.println(e.getMessage());
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ee) {
            System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

No Errors whatsoever. When I input an incorrect file destination I get an error as caught in my catch block.

It seems like the script is simply not executing. Any suggestions?

---

```
#!/bin/bash

pm2 stop test
pm2 start test
pm2 log test
```

Comment: Note that `bash somescript` doesnt at all mean that `system call(somescript)` does work. Because in the first case, you are starting the SHELL and give it a script to read and execute. That is NOT the same as calling that script itself directly.

Comment: `chmod+x` done on the script, yes it is executable. Will check regarding the shebang line thanks. EDIT: Yes shebang included.

Comment: Your file extension is `.bash`. Did you try to use `.sh` instead ?

Comment: @AliCan unix-like systems don't care about file extensions.

Comment: Hmm. The next thing I would do: change the code to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html ... and: dont make it so complicated. Avoid the second file writing. Just run the code locally, and print the exception to stdout. Meaning: go step by step. So, `bash yourscript` works. Does `yourscript` work withint the shell (probably yes). Then just run `java SomeClass` locally (where that class does nothing but use the process builder to run the script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call does not check the stdout/error streams or wait for the process. You will get more information if you change the launch to capture any errors into a file:

```
File stdoutFile = new File("stdout.log");
File stderrFile = new File("stderr.log");
pb.redirectOutput(stdoutFile); 
pb.redirectError(stderrFile); // or pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();

int rc = p.waitFor();
```

As of JDK11 you can use this to print to file:

```
Files.writeString(path, "message", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

On Linux you will need the file to start with `#!/bin/bash' or you may have to change the launch command to specify bash:

String[]cmd = new String[] {"bash", "-c", "/home/ec2-user/test/pm2_StopStart.bash"};

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My bash script starts with `#!/bin/bash`. Would I still need to include the `bash` at the beginning of the `cmd[]` string? I can't seem to get it to run.

Comment: Also, why do I need the `"-c"` ? Currently I have just `new ProcessBuilder("/home/ec2-user/test/pm2_StopStart.bash")`

Comment: I've updated the answer - double check the stderr file after calling `pb.start()`. The "-c" is useful if you don't know whether the next parameter is a shell command - compare `bash ls` vs `bash -c ls` - you are OK without it.

Comment: Thanks, in your answer should you have included also `new File("stderr.log)"`